# Cardinality constrained portfolio in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, portfolio, nonlinear-optimization, quantitative-finance

I am working on portfolio optimization. With MATLAB help I have calculated the risk of portfolio given the expected return with quadprog. Now I want to add cardinality constraints in it, which makes it a mixed integer programming.

I have seen the MATLAB help for mixed integer programming and gaoptimset, which says that **if we are having integer constraint than we can not specify the equality constraints.**
But I have two equality constraints

1. Summation of weights = 1

   w(1) + w(2) + w(3) + .... + w(n) = 1
2. Cardinality Constraint

   support(w) = K

Can somebody please help me in **NONLINEAR MIXED INTEGER PROGRAMMING**

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Dear, if the answer is long then you can e-mail me it on mukeshkumarpareek@gmail.com or if you have a online link for the answer then you can just provide me a link here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please consider taking [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading - carefully and thoroughly - the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. **No one** is going to email you an answer, and hosting a long answer elsewhere defeats the purpose of SO.